# Bootstrap nav not collapsing on emulated/real devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Site in question:
http://marcmurray.net/test_sites/cans/

My bootstrap responsive navbar collapses when I resize the browser window, but on mobile devices and chromes emulated devices the nav simply shrinks. 
My HTML for the navigation is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php" class="activepage">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="why.php">Why Us?</a></li>
                <li><a href="process.php">Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in-between your `<head>` tags. You need this on *any* website for it to be responsive.

Comment: Oops! I've been working off the same old files for too long, forgetting stupid things. Thanks a million!